# How to get the number of decimal places for every Symbol() price

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, mql5, mt4

Certain Currency pairs display values to 5 decimal places (EURUSD), others 4 and so on. I wrote the code below to return the integer value of the decimal places minus one. This function just takes into consideration a few pairs. I would like to expand it to cater for all pairs. How can I find the number of decimal places for each Symbol() price?

```
int decimalPlacesForPairs()  {
   if ((_Symbol == "XAUUSD") || (_Symbol == "USOIL")) {
      return 1;
   }

   else if (_Symbol == "CADJPY") {
      return 2;
   }  

   else return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MQL4 you have access to a predefined variable [int Digits](https://docs.mql4.com/predefined/digitsvar). This function returns the number of digits after the decimal point.

The example given is:

`Print(DoubleToStr(Close[0], Digits));`

Another way, and perhaps a better way in your case is to use [MarketInfo](https://docs.mql4.com/marketinformation/marketinfo). Here you can return the number of decimals places per symbol by inserting the symbol as a string variable.

The example given:

`int vdigits = (int)MarketInfo("EURUSD",MODE_DIGITS);`

In your case you could have a function like the below:

```
int decimalPlacesForPairs(string sPair)  {
   return MarketInfo(sPair),MODE_DIGITS);
}
```

And to call from your `Main(){}`:

```
void Main()
{
    decimalPlacesForPairs(Symbol());
    //or 
    //decimalPlacesForPairs("EURUSD");
}
```

Comment: This **does not answer the problem**. If one reads the O/P, the Question is ***explicit* to say "expand it to cater for all pairs**. How can I find the number of decimal places **for *each* `Symbol()` price?"**

Comment: Of course it does, depending on the context. If the user is planning on using this in an EA and loads it to a chart, the above **WILL** return the decimals for that product it has been loaded on.

Comment: This **does not answer the problem**. The code is missing an iterator, that would cover the requirement to **"expand it to cater for all pairs"** - i.e. **for *each* `Symbol()`** as provided by the Broker, part of which is listed in the Market Watch --- which part of the code is still missing ...

Comment: I see what you are saying @user3666197  I think you would have to create an array with each symbol in the terminal market watch to a file (or print to experts log), and then you could also get the `MODE_DIGITS` for each symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Place your Digits or Pips in the global area.

```html
double pips;
double ticksize = MarketInfo(NULL,MODE_DIGITS);
     if(ticksize==2||ticksize==3||ticksize==4||ticksize==5)
     pips=ticksize*10;
     else pips =ticksize;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only ones that aren't 5 decimals are yen pairs right? Just do a string search to see if it contains yen.

```
string pair="USDJPY";
if(StringFind(pair,"JPY",0)>0)
{
  //Do stuff with 3 decimals
}
else
{
  //Do stuff with 5 decimals
}
```

Or this will do it for you

```
string pair="USDJPY";
double onePip = MarketInfo(pair,MODE_POINT)*10;
double fourPips = MarketInfo(pair,MODE_POINT)*40;
```

note: the last integer in the function is how many pips you want in points (which are 1/10th of a pip)

Comment: Not necessarily.  you have various non fx cfds that may have different decimal places.  Or you may be interpreting different symbol's info other than the symbol of the current chart. @dean's answer above to use [`MODE_DIGITS`, `MODE_POINT`](https://docs.mql4.com/constants/environment_state/marketinfoconstants), et. al is much better in that the built-in function is giving you the symbol info directly from the broker vs you just assuming only JPY pairs are affected.